# C++ friend subclasses access private members (strategy pattern)

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, friend

I've coded a crossover method for a genetic algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)).

The crossover method modifies the private members of the Chromosome class but I pulled it out of Chromosome into a separate pure virtual base class CrossoverStrategy (friend of Chromosome) to keep each crossover method nicely encapsulated in a subclass, i.e. the GoF strategy pattern (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Now the problem is CrossoverStrategy subclasses can't access Chromosome private members because friendship isn't inherited in C++. The only 2 solutions I see are:

1) Add accessor methods to the pure virtual base class e.g. CrossoverStrategy::getGenes() to make Chromosome private members accessible to subclasses. Because CrossoverStrategy can't anticipate all the stuff its subclasses may want to do with Chromosome, I need to expose everything up front. Ugly!

2) Forward declare each CrossoverStrategy subclass and explicitly make it a friend of Chromosome. This feels slightly less ugly, at least keeps the interfaces and code cleaner. I'm leaning towards this option for aesthetics.

Any better design suggestions? Code below.

```
// Chromosome.h ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

class CrossoverStrategy
{
public:
    virtual std::vector<Chromosome*> crossover(Chromosome *parent1, Chromosome *parent2) = 0;
    const std::vector<double> &getGenes(Chromosome *instance) { return instance != NULL ? instance->m_genes : std::vector<double>(); }; // OPTION #1 ... BOO! UGLY!
};

class CrossoverStrategyExample1; // OPTION #2 ... BOO! UGLY!

class Chromosome
{
public:
    // Friends
    friend class CrossoverStrategy;
    friend class CrossoverStrategyExample1; // OPTION #2 ... BOO! UGLY!
private:
    std::vector<double> m_genes;
};

// CrossoverStrategies.h ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#include "Chromosome.h"

class CrossoverStrategyExample1 : public CrossoverStrategy
{
public:
    virtual std::vector<Chromosome*> crossover(Chromosome *parent1, Chromosome *parent2);
private:
};

// CrossoverStrategies.cpp ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#include "CrossoverStrategies.h"

std::vector<Chromosome*> CrossoverStrategyExample1::crossover(Chromosome *parent1, Chromosome *parent2)
{
    // Do something with Chromosome private members
    // PROBLEM ... m_genes not accessible to subclasses? BOO BOO BOO!
    (for unsigned long i = 0; i < parent1->m_genes.size(); i++)
        parent1->m_genes[i] = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Not just ugly, fatal. Thou shall not return reference to local variable.

Comment: Bob is your friend. You trust him with your secrets. But what about Bob's drug-dealing dirtbag of a son, Griff? Do you automatically trust Griff because you trust Bob? Nope. If classes derived from a `friend`were automatically `friend`s, you could subclass whatever you wanted and completely smurf over encapsulation. Not a good plan.

Comment: If you can't possibly pass a null pointer for a pointer, consider passing by references instead of pointers. All but eliminates whole families of accidental screw-ups.

Comment: Given that you want multiple classes/function to have access to data that makes up a `Chromosome`, why isn't the data `public`?

Comment: @Peter because then *anybody* could access the private data. I would prefer if only the friend (and its subclasses) could access. This is a good option 3 but the risk is we un-encapsulate Chromosome entirely.

Comment: "if only the friend (and its subclasses". Friendship is not inherited precisely because *anybody* can creare a subclass of anything. With your access scheme you have zero protection.

Comment: There is always someone who'll find a reason to downvote. It could be that the question leaves out important information like "Must allow non-`const` access to select classes" and "Other classes must be able to use `Chromosome` in the following ways..."  It could be the question is extremely specific to your purposes and of little use to anyone else and therefor "Not Useful." It could be something as trivial as the working code example doesn't work due to a misplaced bracket.

Comment: Thinking on this more, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/asking) may be a better fit for this question. Stack Overflow is generally better for "Why doesn't it work?" and carefully constructed "How do I?" questions. "How should I?" is usually in the domain of engineering. Note that I linked to the help page on asking questions. There are different expectations of what makes for a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 should be rejected because it does not scale. You will be continually modifying `Chromosome` to keep it up to date with new `CrossoverStrategies`.

Option 1 is a strange idea because it places the getter function for `Chromosome`'s data members outside of `Chromosome`. I can see some cases where this is an attractive idea, if `getGenes` is made protected, but I'm not convinced here. Consider instead

## Option 1-A

```
class Chromosome
{
public:
    const std::vector<double>& getGenes() const
    {
        return m_genes;
    }
private:
    std::vector<double> m_genes;
};
```

Everyone who can access a `Chromosome` can access `getGenes`, but they can't do anything to damage it and `Chromosome` remains blissfully ignorant of its users.

## Option 3: Use [The Pimpl Idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Short and stupid example with a few flaws to keep the demo short

Chromosome.h ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#include <vector>
class Chromosome; // forward declaration only
class CrossoverStrategy
{
public:
    virtual ~CrossoverStrategy() = default;
    virtual std::vector<Chromosome*> crossover(Chromosome *parent1, Chromosome *parent2) = 0;
};

Chromosome * ChromosomeFactory(/* some construction parameters here */);
// should also provide a declaration of a factory function to provide CrossoverStrategies
```

CrossoverStrategies.h ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#include "Chromosome.h"

class CrossoverStrategyExample1 : public CrossoverStrategy
{
public:
    virtual std::vector<Chromosome*> crossover(Chromosome *parent1, Chromosome *parent2);
private:
};
```

CrossoverStrategies.cpp ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#include "CrossoverStrategies.h"
class Chromosome
{
public:
    std::vector<double> m_genes;

    // silence a warning
    Chromosome(): m_genes{}
    {

    }
};

// Because Chromosome is only defined in this file, only this file can use the internals 
// of Chromosome. They are public, but the outside world doesn't know that 

Chromosome * ChromosomeFactory(/* some construction parameters here */)
{
    // Probably makes and returns a pointer to a Chromosome,
    // but could pull it from a list, copy construct from a template, etc...
    return new Chromosome(/* some construction parameters here */);
}

// should also provide a definition of a factory function to provide CrossoverStrategies


std::vector<Chromosome*> CrossoverStrategyExample1::crossover(Chromosome *parent1,
                                                              Chromosome *parent2)
{
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < parent1->m_genes.size(); i++)
        parent1->m_genes[i] = 0.0;
    return std::vector<Chromosome*>{}; // silence a warning
}
```

Main.cpp ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#include "Chromosome.h"
#include "CrossoverStrategies.h" // A bad idea. Forces recompilation when strategies are added

int main()
{
    Chromosome * p1 = ChromosomeFactory(/* some construction parameters here */);
    p1->m_genes.push_back(0.0); // will fail to compile (incomplete type)
    Chromosome * p2 = ChromosomeFactory(/* some construction parameters here */);
    
    // probably should hide the next line with a factory as well
    CrossoverStrategy * strategy = new CrossoverStrategyExample1();
    strategy->crossover(p1, p2);
}
```

A quick afterword on security. It always comes at a cost. Generally it makes things harder to use. It makes them harder for an attacker, but it also makes things harder for the legitimate users. Whether it's worth it or not is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm aware of the fact that I'd need to continually modify Chromosome.h when I add a new strategy. But that is a known limitation and (only) 2 lines of code need to change, so it seems like an acceptable tradeoff for the cleanliness of the code.

Comment: Regarding your option 1 suggestion: the whole purpose is to provide non-const access to Chromosome's private members. If we make the getter non-const then any random class could play with Chromsome's privates. Obviously I want to restrict this access only to CrossoverStrategy and its subclasses. Remember, in effect we're taking what was originally Chromosome::crossover() and externalizing it so we can swap out with different strategies. JavaScript does this beautifully with anonymous functions but I find C++ lamdbas ugly and unreadable by comparison.

Comment: @cridgit What sorts of things can non-`CrossoverStrategies` do with `Chromsome`? If the answer is nothing, see if making `Chromsome` `public` and applying [the pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) makes sense.

Comment: The code includes an example of what it needs to do with Chromosome privates: "parent1->m_genes[i] = 0.0;" It needs to access and modify this and perhaps other private members. I looked at pimpl but that also appears to completely hide the private members, so I'm not sure how I'd be able to achieve the desired outcome with pimpl, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The idea of pimpl is the definition of the class is only exposed to the files that need the definition. Everyone else can only see and handle a reference. They can't interact with the object itself. So a `public` access `Chromosome` allows direct, non-`friend` access to it's internals to those who have a definition of the internals and every one else `Chromosome` might as well be entirely `private` right down to the constructors and special member functions.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough example - it actually does look very suitable. One small question: if I have a few public methods to expose e.g. Chromosome::getGeneCount(), where could I do this without breaking the Pimpl pattern?

Comment: I've figured out how to do this using your example above based on the Pimpl pattern and it is exactly what I was looking for. THANK YOU. I used a public ChromosomeImpl variable in the header file. Then I made the ChromosomeImpl members public in the source file so only the CrossoverStrategy subclasses have access to them. Works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

The first, obvious, option is to consider whether the members of `Chromosome` should or should not be `public`.   Given that you want an arbitrary number of classes to have access to its data, an obvious option is to make that data `public`.

A second option is for `Chromosome` to provide a public getter and setter for the affected data, such as;

```
 class Chromosome
 {
      public:

          std::vector<double> getGenes() const {return m_genes;};
          bool setGenes(const std::vector<double> &newgenes)
          {
               bool is_error = true;
               if (IsValid(newgnes))
               {
                    is_error = false;
                    m_genes = newgenes;
               }
               return is_error;    //  return true if change is rejected
          };

       private:

           std::vector<double> m_genes;
 };
```

Then all `CrossOverStrategy` and its derived classes need to do, given valid pointers to `Chromosome`s,  is request the genes,  do whatever is needed, and (when done) provide a new set of genes back to selected `Chromosomes`.

Encapsulation of `Chromosome` is preserved by various measures, since the only way to change genes is via a member function of `Chromosome`   i.e.  there is no way of changing genes in a chromosome outside control of the `Chromosome` class.   Which allows `Chromosome` to do any checks it likes, and reject bad genes if desired.

There is no need for any other class or function to be a friend of `Chromosome`.  A key advantage is that it is not necessary to change the `Chromosome` class whenever a new class is derived from `CrossOverStrategy`.

The trade-off is that genes are retrieved and changes by copying the complete set (potential performance hit of copying).    But it avoids the need to break encapsulation of the `Chromosome` class by providing, directly or indirectly, a reference to its private members to any other classes.

If copying the complete set of chromosomes is a bad thing, work out some additional member functions of `Chromosome` that allow the caller to request partial changes (e.g. update particular genes, insert a set of genes into a specified place in the vector of genes, etc).    These additional functions need to work on the same principle:  all changes of genes within a `Chromosome` go via member functions of `Chromosome`, and there is no "back door" mechanism for other code to sneak changes through.

If you really want, you can make the setter and getter `private` members of `Chromosome`, and make only the base class `CrossOverStrategy` a `friend`.   Then all `CrossOverStrategy` needs to do is provide `protected` helpers that only call the private helpers of `Chromosome`.

```
class CrossoverStrategy
{
    public:
       virtual std::vector<Chromosome*> crossover(Chromosome *parent1, Chromosome *parent2) = 0;

    protected:

        std::vector<double> getGenes(Chromosome *instance)
        {
           return instance ? instance->getGenes() : std::vector<double>();
        };

        bool setGenes(Chromosome *instance, const std::vector<double> &newgenes)
        {
           return instance ? instance->setGenes(newgenes)) : true;  // true indicates error
        };
};
```

That way, only the classes derived from `CrossOverStrategy` can access the `protected` helpers.   If the workings of `Chromosome` change, then the only class that needs to be adapted in this case is the base `CrossOverStrategy` class - since its derived classes don't (directly) access `Chromosome` at all.

Comment: Peter thank you for this solid answer, it seems to be the most "correct" way and certainly not as ugly as the 2 options I suggested. I'll wait to see if there are any other brilliant ideas before accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is fundamentally flawed.

On one hand, you say you don't want *just anyone* to be able to mess with the vector of genes.

On the other hand, you want *any descendant* of `CrossoverStrategy` to be able to mess with the vector of genes.

But there's a contradiction. "Any descendant" of a class *is* "just anyone". Any user is able to inherit from any class and do what they want with your vector of genes. They only need to go through a small one-time inconvenience of inheriting from `CrossoverStrategy`.

This is the reason why friendship in C++ is not inherited. If it were, access control would be useless in presence of friend classes.

Of course you can simulate inheritable friendship by having a protected getter in `CrossoverStrategy` as one of the answers suggests. But doing that defeats the purpose of access control. It makes the arrays of genes as good as public.

Comment: While I agree that making private variables public is to be avoided except in specific circumstances, encapsulation is not binary but a spectrum. Being able to access member variables by subclassing a friend is one step better than 100% public access. So I don't agree that it entirely defeats the purpose of access control - the concept has some merit above just making everything public.

Comment: @cridgit I don't see the spectrum. Access is either open to all or closed. There is no half-open or almost closed.